# Нужно ли ставить тире, если пропущено слово «что»?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Пример:
1. Нет секрета, что я уезжаю.
2. Нет секрета (?) я уезжаю.

Помогите с пунктуацией во втором примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны варианты:

*Нет секрета, я уезжаю.*

*Нет секрета:(какого именно секрета?) я уезжаю.*

*Нет секрета - я уезжаю.* Причинно-следственные связи часто выражаются с помощью тире вместо двоеточия.